# How can I access the props from this taskList array?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to access the props from this taskList array that I'm grabbing from firestore,
The taskList is an array of objects so shouldn't I just be able to access them with task.propName?

```
function App() {
  const [taskList, setTaskList] = useState<Array<object>>()

  const taskCollectionRef = collection(db, "tasks")

  useEffect(() => {
    const getTaskList = async () => {
      // Get data from db
      try {
        const data = await getDocs(taskCollectionRef);
        const filteredData = data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id, }));
        setTaskList(filteredData);
        console.log(taskList);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
    getTaskList();
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <TopNavbar title={siteTitle} />
      <div>
        {taskList?.map((task) => (
          <div>
            <h1>{task.title}</h1> /* Property 'title' does not exist on type 'object'. */ 
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <Auth />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

I've tried changing the type in the useState function but I don't know what else it could be other than an array of objects.

Comment: Did you add types for the items (task) in the array you're mapping over?
Is the response from the server ok?

Comment: In firestore or in the map function?

The response is working correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the object in map:

```
function App() {
  const [taskList, setTaskList] = useState<Array<object>>()

  const taskCollectionRef = collection(db, "tasks")

  useEffect(() => {
    const getTaskList = async () => {
      // Get data from db
      try {
        const data = await getDocs(taskCollectionRef);
        const filteredData = data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id, } as YOUR_OBJECT_TYPE));
        setTaskList(filteredData);
        console.log(taskList);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
    getTaskList();
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <TopNavbar title={siteTitle} />
      <div>
        {taskList?.map((task) => (
          <div>
            <h1>{task.title}</h1> /* Property 'title' does not exist on type 'object'. */ 
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <Auth />
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add the fields coming from the API as a type you can solve it like this:

```
type Task = {
  title: string
  complete: boolean
  tags: string[]
  }
const [taskList, setTaskList] = useState<Array<Task>>()
```

Comment: Thank-you, this combined with the above comment helped me out